# Athena / Presto data last week

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I am currently trying to write an Athena query to fetch all data in a table from the last 7 days.

```
SELECT *
FROM "engagement_metrics"."spikes"
where spike_noticed_moment_utc > date_add('day', -7, now())
```

When running this query I get the following error:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:32: '>' cannot be applied to varchar, timestamp with time zone
```

How can I achieve grabbing data from the last week given the current day in Athena?

Comment: Could you share how `spike_noticed_moment_utc ` is defined, the error message indicates it's a varchar - if so please provide an example on how this column looks like.

Comment: This column looks like `2020-10-29T15:00:34Z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the column `spike_noticed_moment_utc` is defined as varchar, you can cast it quite easy to timestamp using [from_iso8601_timestamp](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "engagement_metrics"."spikes"
where from_iso8601_timestamp(spike_noticed_moment_utc) > date_add('day', -7, now())
```